# BOX2D: смещение по сетке

Tags: box2d, cocos, iphone, cocos2d

Вообщем не могу разработать логику одного смещения. Есть

[image: Сетка]

Есть обычный боксовкий блок. Вообщем не могу разработать его смещение по сетке. Иначе говоря? мы взяли его и сместили только внутри сетки, чтобы он не мог застрять где-то произвольно. Перемещение только по квадратам. Что можете посоветовать? Что-то не могу придумать, как это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Задать тип перемещаемому объекту b2_kinematicBody, что бы дургие объекты не влияли на его позицию.
2. Вычислять любые боксовые координаты блока исходя из логических координат в сетке, которые помножены на шаг сетки.
3. Далее оперировать уже только логическими координатами в сетке (i,j), а для различных плавных эффектов делать интерполяцию, между боксовыми координатами начальной и конечной точки, которые основаны на логических координатах начальной и конечной точки.
4. Скорее всего, блок всегда будет в каком-то из квадратов сетки )

Comment: Шаг в сетке то понятно. Но вот нужно же при таче смещать именно в сетке.

Comment: 1. Ну ) координаты тача нужно будет перевести в логические координаты сетки (i,j). А потом получается инициировать перемещение блока от текущих координат, к новым. 
2. Если вопросы был про то какие именно ячейки должен посетить блок, то тут множество вариантов ). Например взять какой нить алгоритм растеризации линии, который поможет понять через какие ячейки должен пройти блок. Вот алгоритм Брезенхэма(простейший для этой цели)
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0
Пиксель это ячейка сетки.